# Drivers not working properly

Tags: compositing-nodes, drivers

Basically, i made a scene in blender 2.79a, with a node group containing two dilate/erode nodes, and I want them to be relative to the percentage of the resolution. My solution was to use drivers, **but** there seems to be a bug and the drivers don't work, I don't know any python and I have no idea how to solve it.

Any help is very appreciated :)

screenshots:[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey! this appears to be a bug...i recreated your setup and it works fine for me on v2.78.5.

Comment: I tried downloading blender 2.78.5, but it still seems to not work, this is obviously a bug, since it works if the node is outside of the node group.

Comment: Check header of window - if you have alert "**Auto-run disabled**", press **reload trusted**.

Comment: no, I already reported this as a bug

Comment: I'm also getting this in 2.79 test builds but not in 2.78b. Drivers based on node fields don't work if the node is within a group.